# Reading the state of a UISwitch after an asynchronous call

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, uiswitch

I have a loging screen with a UISwitch for letting the user choose "remember me" so I can store his/her credentials on the key chain if desired.

This will only happen if the user has chosen "remember me" AND the server accepts the username/password. However, when the server replies, I have a hard time referring to the state of the UISwitch. The value of myUISwitch.on is, to my surprise (null).

```
NSLog (@"(Successful login. Value of UISwitch rememberMe: %@)", rememberMe.on);
```

Must I store this information in a temporary boolean?

Comment: UISwitch.on is a BOOL (typedefed to signed char), not an id (or other NSObject*), so formatting it with "%@" won't do what you expect. Cast it to int and use "%d", or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is null, it is not the `on` property but the `rememberMe` variable, which is not set. Wire it up correctly in Interface Builder or in code.

Also, make sure to access UIKit always from the main thread, i.e. use performSelectorOnMainThread:`enter code here`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the view still not released by the time you refer to the switch?  Is the `UISwitch` already released by the runtime?  When did you attempt to read its state?  Is the control still on the screen by the time you read its state?